# Kotlin : how to Convert String with HTML numbers to String without HTML numbers

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ascii

I am trying to convert all `HTML numbers` in a string.
I want to convert a String like `"Let&#39;s find"` to `"Let's find"`in `Kotlin`

i tested these but not worked:

`str.toByteArray().toString(Charsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: You are talking about HTML entities, not unicode? Check the HTML class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler).

Comment: BTW—HTML uses Unicode. The numeric character entity references are Unicode codepoint values. Also, keep in mind that if the data is an HTML document, it could have non-text nodes. If you want only the text, you should do more manipulations, such as only the concatentated text from all elements (which is probably a single, simple expression with the appropriate library).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by second in the comments, you need to parse the html string using `Html.fromHtml` and then get the string value from it.

```
var str:String = "Let&#39;s find"
str = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString() 
        } else {
            Html.fromHtml(str).toString() 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

How to encode HTML entities

```kotlin
val encoded: String = "<>&'\"".htmlEncode() // &lt;&gt;&amp;&#39;&quot;
```

How to decode HTML entities

```kotlin
val decoded: String = Html
    .fromHtml("&lt;&gt;&amp;&#39;&quot;", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    .toString() // <>&'"
```

[String.htmlEncode](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/text/package-summary#htmlencode) is a part of the [Core KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#core) library and is syntactic sugar for [TextUtils.htmlEncode](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/TextUtils#htmlEncode(kotlin.String)).

Answer (score 0):

This function convert ascii codes to string

```
 object ASCIIToString {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val num = intArrayOf(65, 120, 98, 75, 115)
        var str: String? = null
        for (i in num) {
            str = Character.toString(i.toChar())
            println(str)
        }
    }
}
```

here i have array you can change it with your string value and remove loop.
you have to loop your string(Let's find) and find ascii code then convert it into string, 
After this you have to replace string in place of asci code from your string(Let's find) 
i hope it will help you.